# Timed Cutout effect - Cubase

Tags: vst, cubase

so I've been creating metal/rock tracks for years now, and I've recent delved into adding a lot of dubstep/electronic/orchestral features into them, but there is an effect I'd love to use but that I'm not sure of the name/technique

It's like a timed cutout, for example If I had a sustained guitar note, it would slowly cut out in 8th notes and then the last bar would have a cutout of 16th notes, much like if you have your bridge pickup muted and you where to toggle between your neck and your bridge pickup. if anyone can tell me the name of this technique or a plugin they know of it would be much appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like *rhythmic gating* - so called because in the pre-computer production days it was often produced by using a separate hardware 'gate' with a side-chain input into which you'd pass a 'key' signal that would open the gate for a short time - http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/1996_articles/sep96/gatetechniques.html.

Of course now you don't really need a separate 'gate' as such - in most DAWs you can just alter the amplitude of the track to switch on and off rapidly, but it might be less work to use a rhythmic gate VST effect, of which there are a number available, or you might find that actually setting up a gate with a side chain as in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dg2vrkvnRak) is a good way to easily set up more complex rhythmic effects.

[Tetsujin](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/12556/tetsujin)  points out in the comment that there's also a Cubase plugin called MidiGate [still there as of Cubase v8] - & an SOS article about it - soundonsound.com/sos/jun07/articles/cubasetech_0607.htm. It looks like it allows you to trigger the gate with MIDI rather than audio into the side chain.

Comment: There's a Cubase plugin ready-made for it - MidiGate [still there as of Cubase v8] - & an SOS article all about it - http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jun07/articles/cubasetech_0607.htm  @topomorto - pointless me 'stealing' an answer just to add this info, so feel free to add to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the effect you are going for. If you literally want it to "cut out", just record the sustained note, set grid to 8th and 16th and cut on grid...select all...shorten regions to create gaps...add fades if desired. If you have all selected they will all shorten and fade. Saves you having to keep track of sidechains and triggers...saves processing too. If you want each 8th note to sound like a muted picked note, use the midi gate. Sidechaining seems unnecessarily complicated for what you are trying to acheive.